# Generated code differs when compiling solution in VS2010 or via MsBuild command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have the following C# code:

```
foreach (var x in m_collection)
{
    m_actionCollection.Add(() =>
    {
        x.DoSomething();
    });
}
```

If I compile the solution in VS2010 the following code is generated (decompiled with IlSpy):

```
foreach (var x in m_collection)
{
    m_actionCollection.Add(() =>
    {
        x.DoSomething();
    });
}
```

If I compile the solution via MsBuild command line the following code is generated:

```
using (List<X>.Enumerator enumerator = this.m_collection.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        X x = enumerator.Current;
        m_actionCollection.Add(() =>
        {
            x.DoSomething();
        });         
    }
}
```

The project file contains

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

and the MsBuild command line looks like the following: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe Solution.sln /property:Configuration=Debug /property:Platform=x86 /maxcpucount /nologo /toolsversion:4.0`

so I assume the compiler is the same, but it isn't...

What must be done/checked to have exactly the same environment for building via MsBuild command line and in VS 2010?

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you're seeing the difference between the C# 5 compiler (invoked via msbuild) and the C# 4 compiler (in VS2010). I'm somewhat surprised that msbuild is using the C# 5 compiler, but it appears to be...

The rules for how a `foreach` iteration variable is captured changed between C# 4 and C# 5. In C# 5, each iteration of the `foreach` loop effectively captures a different variable. In C# 4, all iterations capture the *same* variable.

This means that your original code is effectively broken in C# 4, but is fine in C# 5. In C# 4, you'll fine that if you execute all the actions in `m_actionCollection` afterwards, it will call `DoSomething()` on the last item of `m_collection` lots of times (`m_collection.Count` times). In C# 5, it will call `DoSomething` once on each item of `m_collection`.

It doesn't help that it's not clear what version of the language ILSpy is effectively decompiling to :(

> What must be done/checked to have exactly the same environment for building via MsBuild command line and in VS 2010?

I would strongly suggest that the simplest approach would be to move to VS2012 or VS2013 instead.

You can check that by looking at the msbuild logs, and seeing which version of `csc.exe` is being used for the `CoreCompile` step. Once you know which compiler *binary* is being used, you can run just the compiler from the command line to tinker as you see fit.

When I run `msbuild` with `/toolsversion:4.0` it uses `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe`, which itself reports:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.33440
>   for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

That appears to be a C# 5 compiler, despite the name. I suspect that's due to .NET 4.5 being an in-place upgrade.

The simplest way of checking which compiler you're really using is to try to include an `async` method. For example, here's a complete class:

```
class Test { static async void Foo() {} }
```

If compiling that gives a *warning* CS1998 ("This async method lacks await operators...") then it's using a C# 5 compiler. Older compiler will give an error (probably "Invalid token 'void'...")

Comment: Yes I know that my code is broken, but without that I wouln't have noticed that different compiler versions were used :-).

How can MsBuild to be forced to use the same compiler version than VS2010?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Despite all the version number confusions, where can the csc.exe for .NET 4.0 (C# 4.0) as VS 2010 is using be found?

Comment: @Harry13: That i couldn't tell you, I'm afraid - partly as I don't have it installed myself. It's *possible* that it isn't even available in a standalone form, but I suggest you look for all occurrences of `csc.exe` on your machine. Again, I'd encourage you to upgrade if possible :)

Comment: It is the same executable. Found that by comparing the detailed MsBuild output from VS and from command line MsBuild. Also in the command line arguments seems to be nothing different which is relevant to that problem.

In the MsBuild log of the command line build the following message seems to be suspect:
Using "Csc" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

This occurs only in MsBuild but not in VS2010

Comment: @Harry13: That's *very* strange. Unfortunately without VS2010 installed, it's going to be hard for me to reproduce and dig further :(

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to upgrade in short time so I'll stick with that some more time ;-(. Maybe somebody else can jump in?

Comment: @Harry13: When Jon Skeet speaks, the rest watches and learns, no one jumps :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts